# Bandwidth and latency between North America and Europe

Tags: networking, azure

I am working on a feasibility study for an application. The user base will be in North America but the company I work for is based in the UK. The application will be fairly data intensive and will utilize AJAX web services to implement interactive selection of content. There will also be a facility to generate and download pdf files.

I am wondering if there is any disadvantage in hosting the application in the UK for NA users, i.e. would the bandwidth and latency associated with navigating the puddle between the 2 continents be a factor that needs to be considered in deciding where to host the application?

As an example would one expect the performance of an Azure application for North American users be appreciably different if hosted on the North America vs. North Europe data centres?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you need to worry about it.  We use Azure extensively in both the NA and EMEA regions.  We get much faster throughput and much lower latency when working from a data center in your client region.  I don't have great numbers to share with you, but I would estimate a 3-5X difference.

Is there a reason you can't host a secondary site in EMEA with the read model of the data and send writes to the US?

The best way to proceed may just be to do some testing.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. The choice may actually be between hosting within the company infrastructure in the UK vs. Azure in North America. We are at an early stage of planning so I am simply trying to understand if this is something we need to consider and maybe test for. Your answer tells me that yes, it is........

Answer (score 0):

It may sound strange, but I had some apps running on West US and after I moved to Europe's datacenters my services are faster than before. (some instance sizes / numbers)